# How to make https request in service

Tags: angularjs

I am invoking a service with `$http` protocol, but the url that I need to invoke is of *https* protocol.
As a result I am getting error with code : 403.

Snippet:

```
return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://test.com', /* sample url */
            headers: some_header,
            data: some_data
        });
```

I have tried the same using HTML - form, and it worked there, so I don't think, it's an issue with the url.

I guess, this error is mainly because of `$http`.
How can one make https call in AngularJS using *service* or *factory*?

Comment: please share full response with headers when you got received 403.

Comment: @shashank did my answer answer your question ?

Comment: @Kit, yes, it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that
>   accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely
>   forbidden for some reason. This article contains basic troubleshooting
>   instructions for 403 Forbidden errors.
>   [source](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644980/why-am-i-seeing-a-403-forbidden-error-message)

Using Angular's $http service works with https. [Here's](https://embed.plnkr.co/8Bj3wEKl97beCe295WTQ/) a basic plunker doing exactly that. It retrieves a resource over https and updates $scope.results with the result.

```
$http.get('https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/77OOwJ/')
    .then(function(data){
      $scope.results = data; 
    })
```